# Unit Testing Database Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

**Problem:** So an issue that I have been running into lately as a beginner to unit testing, is dealing with classes that have heavy database usage.

**Technologies Used:** Typescript, SinonJS, Node-Postgres and Jest

**Example:** For the given function

```js
public async insertUserDetails() {

  const confirmationCode = this.generateConfirmationCode();

  try {

    await this.db.query({
      text: 'INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, registration_date, confirmation_code) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING *',
      values: [this.firstname, this.lastname, this.email, this.password, this.registrationDate, confirmationCode]
    });


  } catch (error) {

    throw error;

  }

}
```

**Question:**
Would a suitable unit test be to make sure that the db.query() function is called with the correct sql such as the following? Or would this be considered a waste of time and a ***brittle*** test?

```js
test("should format correct sql", async () => {

    //Test Setup
    const user = new User({
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "doe",
        email: "email@example.com",
        password: "some_password_hash",
        registrationDate: "some_random_date",
    });

    //Mocks
    const queryStub = sinon.stub(user.db, "query");
    const confirmationCode = sinon.stub(user,'generateConfirmationCode').returns("48fsakb8a-cfjdab");

    const sampleQuery = {
        text: 'INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, registration_date, confirmation_code) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING *',
        values: [user.firstname, user.lastname, user.email, user.password, user.registrationDate, confirmationCode]
    }

    //Preform
    await user.insertUserDetails();

    //Assert
    sinon.assert.calledWith(queryStub, sampleQuery);


});
```

Or should I skip unit tests all together on these type of functions and classes and set up an integration test database and test these cases via integration tests?

This is a very simplified example as I did not go into testing Database transactions, but testing transactions become an even larger can of worms, as there are multiple queries being preformed.

Thank you for any help! This is driving me crazy -__-

Comment: `catch (error) { throw error; }` is pointless. Just drop the `try`/`catch` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a suitable unit test be to make sure that the db.query()
>   function is called with the correct sql such as the following?

What you are trying to do is not unit test if you focus on making db.query. Then it becomes an integration test. Here your unit, which you want to test, is  `insertUserDetails`. So you focus on behavior of this function. What you can test is: 1. that db.query is called with correct parameters (hoping this.db can be mocked) 2. If db.query throws exception, then your catch block is executed and your exception is thrown.

Similarly you should try to write unit test for `this.db` class covering `query` function.

So once you have made sure, both unit's are properly covered, then it shall be a good start.

Now if you have option of writing integration test in one shot, where you can use some kind of in memory database or may be a real database at your disposition, then go ahead and do that and you can not write the unit tests altogether.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so yes my db connection is injected into the class that im using so mocking it will be no issue, but if im not making sure that the correct sql is generated from the input, what will my test actually be testing? it will always succeed because im passing through hard coded "correct" data. Or am I still missing something fundamental?

Comment: If there is a way where you can extract the query creation part also in another function, then do that refactoring and write unit test for that. How about it?

Comment: this actually works! thank you. I provided bad data for a failure test, and good data for a passing test, then in my integration test suite, test the system with the database. Thank You.